# Comparing fmap type declaration to how it's used

Tags: haskell

I ran `:t fmap (*) (Just 5)` and got

```
fmap (*) (Just 5) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
```

Type declaration of fmap says

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So am I right in thinking that `(*)` is being treated as `(a -> (a -> a))` and corresponds to `(a -> b)` part of the fmap type declaration? If the `(a -> a)` part corresponds to `b`, why can't I do the following? And let the `b` represent the lambda function?

```
foo :: a -> b
foo x = (\y -> y + 3)
```

Comment: Because `b` in the signature means *to any type you like*.

Comment: You're question about the type of `(*)` is correct. Regarding `foo`, what type variables end up being will be dictated by the caller.  This concept took a while to sink in for me. Barring type class constraints and advanced extensions, you can't write `foo` in such a way that constrains what `b` is. `\y -> y + 3` is of type `Num a => a -> a`, and you can't hide that behind type variable `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an implicit [`forall`](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall) in your signature:

```
foo :: forall a b. a -> b
```

This means that your function must work for ***any*** `a` and `b`. Let's have a look at your function:

```
foo x = (\y -> y + 3)
```

Since `x` isn't restricted on the right hand side of `=`, it fulfils the requirements: it can be of any type. However, your right hand side has the following type:

```
ghci> :t (\y -> y + 3)
Num k => k -> k
```

Remember that your original function said that the choice of `b` can be arbitrary. However, your function's body restricts the return type to `b ~ Num k => k -> k`. You would have to use

```
foo :: Num b => a -> b -> b
```

By the way, foo's type already shows that you will not use the first argument, because there's no way to combine two values of different types in a general way. Indeed, one can proof that `foo` is `const bar` for some `bar :: Num b => b -> b`.

#### Exercises

- Try to think of a function with type `forall a b. a -> b`.

Comment: @Zeta ty for the answer, I think I get it now. Just one last question. Since `b` can be anything in `foo`, even if we got rid of `+ 3`, it wouldn't work because `(\y -> y)` can't match for e.x. a String type. Also doesn't work because the type declaration says only takes 1 argument, but I'm taking in 2 arguments?

Comment: @Jae: That's correct. `\y -> y` (also called `id`) has type `k -> k`, which restricts `b`.

Answer (score 1):

In your initial example, `a` is constrained to be an instance of `Num` because of the `5` and the `(*)`.

```
:type 5
   5 :: Num a => a

:type (*)
   (*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You are correct that the `(a->a)` gets unified with the `b` in the type of `fmap`.

```
:type (\y -> y + 3)
    (\y -> y + 3) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Hence:

```
:type foo
   foo :: Num a => t -> a -> a
```

As Willem Van Onsem says, `b` means "any type you like", not "any type that fits the invisible constraints I haven't mentioned".